# Dlang: foreach loop or "each" template

Tags: d

Say I have an iterable array of objects and I want to loop over each of those objects and perform some task or tasks. I see two ways of doing this, which are listed below. I have timed both using MonoTime and they seem to be comparable as far as execution time goes.

Which of these options is recommended for use in D? And in what scenarios might the recommended option not be useful for?

```
    int[] animals = [animal1, animal2, animal3];

    // OPTION 1

    foreach(Animal a; animals) {
        a.feed();
        a.giveWater();
    }

    // OPTION 2
    animals.each!( (a) {a.feed();
                        a.giveWater();
                        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` is the default.

The one thing I'd use `each` for is applying a lot of transforms to a collection (with std.algorithm) and then iterating over the result. This is for readability alone. Consider if you wanted to iterate over the following:

```
students
    .filter!(s => s.year == 1)
    .map!(s => s.major)
    .filter!(m => m !is null)
    .map!(x => faculty.byProgram(x))
    .joiner
    .array
    .sort
    .uniq
```

It would be awkward to put that in a foreach. It would be natural to tack on a `.each!(x => writeln(x.name))`.

Comment: The other obvious use case for `each` is when creating delegates from within a loop. In regular `foreach` it actually captures the last iterated value, `.each` mitigates this by creating a copy that is captured.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `each` to call a function directly.

For example:

```
[1, 2, 3].each!writeln();
```